# Simplest way to create pulsating (looping) background in Raphael JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I am looking for the simplest and more straightforward way for making a looping/repeating puslating background of some element.

E.g. if I have a circle:

```
var filler = {
            'fill': 'white',
            'stroke': 'white',
            'stroke-width': '0'
}
var fillerHover = {
            'fill': '#b6def1',
            'stroke': '#b6def1',
            'stroke-width': '0',
            'cursor': 'pointer'
}

circle.hover(function() {
            circle.animate(fillerHover, 500);
        },

        function() {
            circle.animate(filler, 500);
        }
);
```

This code above is working well, however it animates the transition only once and I would like to make a repeating loop as long as I am hovering over the circle.

And I want to loop the background when I have cursor on the circle from filler to fillerHover until I go out with the cursor.

How to create such loop in the simplest way?

Comment: Is it something with repeat(infinity) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a callback to the animation that starts it again: http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.animate

Don't do it in a `setInterval`, that will f**k up the framerate!
Don't even use `requestAnimationFrame`. You don't know when it will trigger animation. The only 'safe' way to do this is let Raphael tell you when the animation finished (via the `callback` option) to start the next animation.

Something like:

```
fillerHover.callback = mouseOver;
function mouseOver() {
  circle.animate(fillerHover, 500);
}

circle.hover(
  mouseOver,
  function() {
    circle.animate(filler, 500);
  }
);
```

Mix that with your current code =) You know what I mean.

**EDIT:** This looks like it: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/j9XyX/6/show/

Comment: I'm kinda new to Raphael myself. Very cool stuff! I'm never making PNGs again! SVG is awesome but doesnt work in IE8. And now it does =) A glowing circle aint nothin ;)

Comment: It is working, however it causes some problem and the browser (firefox 14) starts to react slow and eventually freeze after a while. Anyway, thanks for the effort I appreciate it very much.

Comment: Works fine for me... Makes sense though. Animating SVG elements (without GPU, like this) is heacy stuff. If it's just a circle, you might want to use CSS3 border-radius, animation & transition. You can trigger the GPU for better performance.